# jQuery toggleClass() on checkbox label is not yielding desired outcome

Tags: jquery

I can't for the life of me figure out why this .toggleClass() method is not working.

I use it all the time, so I'm perplexed...

I've striped the code down to the essentials and built [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/xVJ83/)

Tell me I'm not crazy?

### HTML

```
<ul class="ingredient-list">

    <li>
      <label for="ingredient01" class="toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ingredient01" />
        <span class="item-amount">1</span>
        toggle class example
      </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label for="ingredient02" class="add">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ingredient02" />
        <span class="item-amount">2</span>
        add class example
      </label>
    </li>

</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.ingredient-list {

    list-style: none;
    margin: 1rem 0 2rem;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      float: left;
      padding: .5em;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px solid red;
      float: left;
      padding: .5em;
    }
    .item-amount {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
      background-color: orange;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 400;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .ingredient-aquired {
      background-color: green;
    }

} // .ingredient-list
```

### jQuery

```
// when the user clicks or taps the ingredient,
//    toggle the color of the item amount

$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.item-amount').toggleClass('ingredient-aquired');
});

$('.add').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.item-amount').addClass('ingredient-aquired');
});
```

Comment: `toggleClass` works fine. It's your DOM traversal logic that is flawed.

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't your fiddle work?

Comment: @j08691 No, it doesn't work if clicking the label instead of the checkbox.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I guess that is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
$('.toggle').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.item-amount').toggleClass('ingredient-aquired');
});
$('.add').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.item-amount').addClass('ingredient-aquired');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xVJ83/17/)

The problem was that, if you clicked the `<label>`, you detected the click of both `<input>` and `<label>`, so the class toggled twice.

Then, better listen to `change` event.

Comment: Why should he use change over click?

Comment: Because of checkbox element

Comment: Good explanation. @j08691: because if you toggle twice, it goes back to first state. BTW, I don't understand why OP was downvoted

Comment: @matthijs I was pretty confused by that too. I gave quality documentation, and I did tons of research before asking here.

Comment: @Oriol - Awesome answer. Thank you for explaining what was actually happening - as well as reminding me about `change` - which will help in other ways as well!